# iOS UIWebView Javascript - insert data -receive callbacks?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

I have a webpage.  I have a javascript file that does a whole lot of stuff.  In the app I have an NSString with some crucial data that needs to be processed in the javascript file.  How do I get my string value into a certain place in my html so my javascript can read it?

Also, the javascript will produce certain data when actions are performed (like pressing a button), how do I retrieve the data from the webview/javascript so it can be stored in the app?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can call a javascript method and pass the value by using this

```
NSString *selectedValue = [webViewInstance stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"getAndReturnRadioValue(%d)", questionCounterIntValue]];
```

But to trigger back from javascript you need to use a workaround method,

Implement the following webViewDelegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSLog(@"passed data from web view : %@",[[request URL] query]);

    if([[[request URL] query] isEqualToString:@"clickedOnLineNo"])
    {
        //Do your action here    
    }
}
```

You have to navigate to a fake URL from your javascript method like,

```
window.location = "someLink://yourApp/form_Submitted:param1:param2:param3";
```

on a button click or your required action.

You could take a look at my answer for this question
[Submit a form in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466875/submit-a-form-in-uiwebview)

Comment: Can you elaborate further on getting data from the javascript? For instance, if you click a button in the html, it will trigger a javascript function. That function has a return value that I need.  How do I get that return value?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer navigate to an URL from your JS function- it will fire the delegate method.

Answer (score 4):

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

sounds like exactly the method you need.  If, for example, the input and output need to interact with the JavaScript can be done with a single method, you can pass a value into JavaScript and get the results with something like the following code:

```
NSString* jsCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"doSomething('%@')", dataToPass];
NSString* resultFromJavaScript = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
```

Comment: I was missing the ' ' surrounding %@... Uff, 1 hour later! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi we can send the data from objective c to javascript and can callback from javascript easily

Objective-C --> javaScript

**In Objective-C class**

```
NSData *locationCountData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:locationCount   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *locationCountString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:locationCountData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *locationCountData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:locationCount options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *locationCountString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:locationCountData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *str = [NSString   stringWithFormat:@"testFunction(%@,%@)",locationCountString, locationsListString];
[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: str];
```

**in JavaScript file**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testFunction(locationCount,locationList)
{
    alert(locationCount + locationList);
}
</Script>
```