# Communicating between JS and UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I present a web page on a `UIWebView`.

This page posts a message with `window.webkit.messageHandlers`and I want to "observe" this event: how can I achieve this using a simple `UIWebView`?

Notice that I'm easily able to achieve the result using a `WKWebView`, but the question is if it is possible with a `UIWebView` too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS UIWebView Javascript - insert data -receive callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681918/ios-uiwebview-javascript-insert-data-receive-callbacks)