# return array from javascript function to objective-c xcode

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode, arrays

IS it possible to get a array of strings from Javascript. I mean I am calling javascript in my code for iPhone app. Now After the functions completes I want to return the array of string to the objective C code back. How can I return the array back and how my objective-c code can read that array?

Thanks
Akansha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use webview's

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

delegate method. See my answer here.

[iOS UIWebView Javascript - insert data -receive callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681918/ios-uiwebview-javascript-insert-data-receive-callbacks/7682794#7682794)

UPDATE FOR COMMENT:

and this one,

[Submit a form in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466875/submit-a-form-in-uiwebview)

Comment: ok thanks Elanthiraiyan. I wil try this and will get back you.

Comment: I saw the link. In that what exactly "clickedOnLineNo" mean? I mean I am not able to get what does "clickedOnLineNo" actually do.

Comment: I have added another one of answer. Have a look at that

Comment: thanks, this one looks to be more elaborative. I will try this. Thanks a lot for your help. I will inform you if I get my things working. Thanks again !

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your help was really awesome. It worked. Thanks you so so much . Elanthiraiyan. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more direct way to do it. Call `JSON.stringify` on the `JSON` object to be returned from your function. Then convert that string to an NSDictionary, something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356842/how-to-use-nsjsonserialization).